# How to combine two DATES variables in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, date, variables

I have a data frame as following

```
Sample_ID<-c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6")
Heart_attack<-c("2010/04/13", "2008/07/30", "2009/03/06", "2008/08/22", "2009/06/24", "2008/08/26")
Stroke<-c("2007/05/17", "2009/05/16", "2007/05/16", "2007/05/16","2007/05/16", "2010/05/16")
DF<-data.frame(Sample_ID,Heart_attack,Stroke)
```

I need to make TWO COLUMNS. One  column in this dataframe called `CVD_date`. All i want is that among the `Heart_attack` and `Stroke`, the event occurred earlier that "date" should be included in this variable. For example i am looking for following output.
The second column `CVD` should show `1` if the event reported in `CVD_date` is of `Heart_attack` and `2` otherwise.
For example i am looking for following output.

```
Sample ID  Heart_attack  Stroke        CVD_date         CVD
 a1         2010/04/13   2007/05/17    2007/05/17        2
 a2         2008/07/30   2009/05/16    2008/07/30        1
 a3         2009/03/06   2007/05/16    2007/05/16        1
```

How to do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pmin` to get minimum between `Heart_attack` and `Stroke` date. For `CVD` we compare both the dates, convert the logical values to integer and add 1 which will give 1 if `Stroke` is greater than `Heart_attack` date and 2 otherwise..

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  mutate(across(-1, lubridate::ymd), 
         CVD_date = pmin(Heart_attack, Stroke), 
         CVD = as.integer(Heart_attack > Stroke) + 1)

#  Sample_ID Heart_attack     Stroke   CVD_date CVD
#1        a1   2010-04-13 2007-05-17 2007-05-17   2
#2        a2   2008-07-30 2009-05-16 2008-07-30   1
#3        a3   2009-03-06 2007-05-16 2007-05-16   2
#4        a4   2008-08-22 2007-05-16 2007-05-16   2
#5        a5   2009-06-24 2007-05-16 2007-05-16   2
#6        a6   2008-08-26 2010-05-16 2008-08-26   1
```

---

In the older version you can do :

```
DF %>%
  mutate_at(-1, lubridate::ymd) %>%
  mutate(CVD_date = pmin(Heart_attack, Stroke), 
         CVD = as.integer(Heart_attack > Stroke) + 1)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. But which package contains this function "across". ? I am getting error.

Comment: It is present in new `dplyr`. You can install it by doing `install.packages('dplyr')`

Comment: Can you write the two commands each for each variable separately so that i can understand better.

Comment: package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

Comment: I have updated the answer which works for older version of `dplyr`.

Comment: Thank you. I segregated your code into two to simplify and it worked in both ways.
DF$CVD_date = pmin(Heart_attack, Stroke) 
DF$CVD = as.integer(Heart_attack > Stroke) + 1